# Tomcat memory settings

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, out-of-memory

I am getting out of memory exception in my tomcat,Could any one explain how to do settings and what are best values have to set based on calculation of my total memory.Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Chaitu

Comment: Which version of tomcat, and which operating system?

Comment: skaffman:I am using Tomcat 6.0 version.

Comment: better to add some stack trace as well

Comment: I am not getting any issues now,but i am trying to set better memory settings to avoid the memory issues in future.

Comment: Any suggestions or help please.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat uses java startup flags to set memory configuration.  You'll want to set your JAVA_OPTS environment variable to include -Xmx512m ( or however much heap space you think you'll need ).

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

If you get PermGen memory exceptions you may need to also set MaxPermSize:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
```

The normal catalina startup scripts will incorporate the JAVA_OPTS environment variable into their normal startup process.

Comment: +1 for mentioning PermGen memory issues. They tend to happen quite often.

Comment: Thanks for answer,How can i measure  values here,Any mathematical formula to measure these settings.

Comment: FYI for Tomcat6 put these in setenv.sh (or setenv.bat and use `set JAVA_OPTS`)